# How to pronounce 自払

Tags: pronunciation

ゆうちょ銀行 uses 自払 in the description of automatic payment transactions. I guess 自払 is an abbreviation of 自動支払. Should 自払 be pronounced as じはらい?

Comment: It's short for [自動払込み（じどうはらいこみ）](http://www.jp-bank.japanpost.jp/hojin/smart/hj_smt_autharaikomi.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be read 「じ**ば**らい」and not 「じ**は**らい」.

In case you are unfamiliar with [rendaku, please read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku).